# slearn standard scaler transform VS fit_transform output

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scaling, sklearn-pandas

I am using sklearn standard scaler to normalized some column in a pandas data frame. While fit_transform work as expected, transform does not. Here is what I do:

```
non_categorical_variable = ['var1','var5']
scaler = StandardScaler()
train[non_categorical_variable] = scaler.fit_transform(train[non_categorical_variable])
```

And it works perfectly, but this does not work:

```
test[non_categorical_variable] = scaler.transform(test[non_categorical_variable])
```

And this is the error message:

> File "main_FM.py", line 286, in predict_first_stage
>
> test[non_categorical_features] = scaler.transform(test[non_categorical_features])
>
> TypeError: 'coo_matrix' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Now if I simply type the following everything works and matches.

```
print test[non_categorical_variable]
print scaler.transform(test[non_categorical_variable])

print type(test[non_categorical_variable])
print type(scaler.transform(test[non_categorical_variable]))

print test[non_categorical_variable].shape
print scaler.transform(test[non_categorical_variable]).shape
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you mock up some sample data for us to test on?

Comment: would be great if you could give the output of those print statements. And even greater if you could create a minimal example reproducing the error. When you call `transform` is it on the previously fitted `scaler` or on a new one? This may come from a strange and not fully mature interaction of sklearn with pandas (I'd fully convert the relevant columns to numpy first and recheck).

Comment: Is `non_categorical_features` a list? The error you are showing does not come from scaler (unless you have posted a part of the error message). Also in the print statements you are using `non_categorical_variable` not `non_categorical_features`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Indeed, I think that the error is coming from the line after which is HotOneEncoding but there is a bug in the error report and the wrong line is reported. I am investigating this. I will update the post or re-post if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Probably `test` is a sparse matrix, while `train` is not. Therefore `test[non_categorical_variable]` fails because sparse matrices don't support the gettitem interface.

If you're using OneHotEncoder, you can set its `sparse` argument to false.